# How to change a GUID column of a SQLite database file to its string equivalent

Tags: database, sqlite, database-schema, guid

I am using SQLite as my database. I have a couple of tables and in some of the tables the primary key is of type GUID. Is there any way to replace that column with the string equivalent of the GUID key?

PS 1:It seems that SQLite has some limitations in modifying the schema of a table. 
PS 2:I need to keep the current records of the DB

Comment: SQLite uses manifest typing; you can store any type of data in any type of column. SQLite also does not have a GUID type; it's just a string. You don't need to do anything to convert it.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo , Thanks for your comment. You are right. The column data type is just called "guid" and it is not a real data type. The problem is that the value is stored as binary and not as text.

Comment: In that case, try `SELECT hex(guid) FROM table`. That will give the GUID in hex.